# Installation of tf.js giving problem with numpy==1.15.1 version

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use `tensorflow.js` for browser. When I installed `tf.js` on my system (Windows 10 64-bit, Pycharm community 2019.1) using conda virtual env, the following error occurs:

```
(tjfs) A:\modakatech\tjfs>tensorflowjs_converter --version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 980, in _find_and_load SystemError: 
<class'_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an 
error set ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2019-06-03 10:49:29.186367: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] 
Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr
```

`tensorflow.js` installation requires package `numpy==1.15.1`, `keras` and more.
I have tried to upgrade `numpy` to latest version but `tensorflow.js` showing that `numpy` version should be `numpy==1.15.1`. My current version of `numpy` is 1.16 which is incompatible.

```
Pycharm Error->ERROR: tensorflowjs 1.1.2 has requirement numpy==1.15.1, but you'll have 
numpy 1.16.4 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should uninstall your numpy

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

and install the proper version

```
pip install numpy==1.15.1
```

Edit:
If you are using conda - To uninstall use:

```
conda remove -n *your_env_name* numpy
```

To install specific version:

```
conda install -n *your_env_name* numpy=1.15.1
```